# How to have ASP.NET Core running locally with HTTPS in Kubernetes

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I currently have a docker-compose setup for ASP.NET Core. However when moving to test the cluster in Kubernetes I ran into SSL issues with Kestrel. Originally with Docker/Docker-compose you can set up local SSL with

```sh
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\<app_name>.pfx -p <password>
```

Then

```sh
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Finally

```sh
dotnet user-secrets set "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" "<password>"
```

And in Docker-compose I setup the volumes to point to this cert

```yaml
volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/
```

I am curious how I can test locally https with kubernetes. I saw a git repo https://github.com/Lybecker/k8s-friendly-aspnetcore, however I did not figure out how to get the .pfx file from my local computer into the secret, I would think copy and paste is not the way to go.

I looked at this SO post [Access .NET Core app on Kubernetes on both http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661594/access-net-core-app-on-kubernetes-on-both-http-and-https)

However it looks like they are using .Net 5 which uses .key and .crt. I am on .Net 3.1 which uses a .pfx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than deploying your .NET core container with https, you should deploy it with http and use nginx-ingress to provide https as described here: https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/nginx-ingress/

Comment: What if my service uses gRPC or any HTTP2 based protocol (which requires TLS certificate)?

Comment: this is basically a link-only answer, and the provided link is dead. @Peter, could you provide an updated link?