# How to make sure my .NET Core service running in EKS can find the https port?

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, https, amazon-eks

I have created a .NET Core microservice using Microsoft sign-in as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031953/how-to-set-the-redirect-uri-when-using-microsoft-sign-in-in-a-net-5-application). When running it locally or in a local Docker container, everything is working as expected. However, when running in [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/), I get an annoying warning message in the logs:

> Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

This warning is shown in this picture shown below which also shows that I also checked which port numbers are used (only 80 for http). I would be nice if `netstat -tulp` would show a port number for https because then I can just set it in the application settings ([as explained by the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#port-configuration)) ad resolve it directly.

The Microsoft docs clearly exlain what to do when

> The middleware logs the warning "Failed to determine the https port
> for redirect."

but these do not make clear what to do if everything works fine in all environments except when running the application in EKS. Probably, I should do something in my EKS/Kubernetes configuration but I have no clue what to do.

Here is the service file:

[image]

Here is the warning message shown in the logs.

[image]

How do I resolve the warning message?

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using `app.UseHsts();` in `Startup.cs` file which will force client to use https. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts).

But basic on your log `Now listening on: http://[::]:80`, your service only listening on http but not https.

Maybe You can try this

1. Simply delete the code `app.UseHsts();` and use only http.
2. Enable https by config `spec.template.spec.containers.env` in k8s deployment.yaml. You will need a server tls cert in your container.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapi
  labels:
    app: weather-forecast
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: webapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: weather-forecast
        service: webapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapi
          image: exploredocker.azurecr.io/webapi:v1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
              value: https://+:443;http://+:80
            - name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path
              value: /https/server_cert.pfx
            - name: ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password
              value: password
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is actually listening for HTTPS connections on the port in your config:
`targetPort: 9377`, `nodePort: 30098`

This other similar question might help resolve some issues with your setup:
[Access .NET Core app on Kubernetes on both http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661594#:%7E:text=I%20have%20a%20working%20Docker-Compose%20setup%20which%20I%20am%20trying%20to%20port%20to%20Kubernetes). If those are not issues with your setup, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079189/8570169) by **yip102011** is good.