# ASP.NET Core 6 running in k8s shutting down

Tags: asp.net, kubernetes, .net-6.0

OK I´m new to ASP.NET Core 6 and k8s. So far all apps I was hosting (java, js, python) didn't have any issue.

Deployment service and ingress were created successfully but I was having error in pod:

> {"EventId":3,"LogLevel":"Warning","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware","Message":"Failed
> to determine the https port for redirect.","State":{"Message":"Failed
> to determine the https port for redirect.

I have always managed certificates at ingress level and so far with no issues. I'm always using Nginx also as IC.

After some research I end up with following post:

[How to make sure my .NET Core service running in EKS can find the https port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69045532/how-to-make-sure-my-net-core-service-running-in-eks-can-find-the-https-port)

So basically I decided to remove the C# code the https redirection I saw in developers code and rebuild image `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` . This way I can managed security ssl as I said, from ingress level. (Here is the commented line)

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

So now I tested new Docker image locally and it works.

[image]

But inside kubernetes I'm getting:

[image]

There are no redirects errors but I'm just getting "application is shutting down now".

Any idea what this can be related to?

Ingres secret with certificates were created successfully and ingres is using that secret for tls.

here describe pod.

[image]

Comment: what does `kubectl describe pod <podname>` show for this app ? any events? last termination etc.

Comment: @Radek'Goblin'Pieczonka just added that. Liveness probe failed. But still don´t get why is getting down

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your configuration, but I had the similar "application is shutting down now" issue and found out that I missed .AddHealthChecks() and .UseHealthChecks("/health") in Startup.cs file. Your reason can be different, but maybe this will give you a hint :)

Comment: Similar situation but in k8s. I answer my own question with the solution

Answer (score 0):

ok So Application was running but giving 404, so k8s interpreted that as unhealthy.
So I added the health check in the liveness and readiness probe like:
path: /healthy  and that way it started to give the 200 code and container started to run normally.